# How to secure connection string in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

I have enabled MSI and added it to secure key vault. I want to retrieve the password from Key Vault and pass it to the connection string in application settings of app service.

How can I do that?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow @user512, I hope that you will take the time to review [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) because this question lacks detail and is impossible for us to answer.

Comment: Ultimately you cannot do it the way you want (replacing app settings). You have to write code which reads the secrets from the Key Vault. And the way you do that depends on your framework.